# Prolog - Creating a list of all the possible shifts of another list?

Tags: list, prolog, rotation

For my assignment I need to create a list of all the possible shifts (rotations) of another list in prolog. For example,

```
Prototype: all_shifts(+A,-R,+L,+S)  *S will always start at 1*

?- length([1,2,3,4],L), all_shifts([1,2,3,4],R,L,1).
L = 4,
R = [[2, 3, 4, 1], [3, 4, 1, 2], [4, 1, 2, 3]].
```

Currently, I have a program that shifts it to the left once.

```
one_shift(A, R) :-
   rotate(left, A, R).

rotate(left, [H|T], L) :- append(T, [H], L).
```

However, I need to create another program in which the final result (R) contains all of the possible shifts. Recursion in prolog is really beginning to confuse me, but I'm pretty sure that's whats required. Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stay logically pure using `same_length/2` and `append/3`!

```
list_rotations(Es, Xss) :-
   same_length(Es, [_|Xss]),
   rotations_of(Xss, Es).

rotations_of([], _Es).
rotations_of([Xs|Xss], Es) :-
   same_length([_|Xss], Suffix),
   same_length(Es, Xs),
   append(Suffix, Prefix, Xs),
   append(Prefix, Suffix, Es),
   rotations_of(Xss, Es).
```

Sample query:

```
?- list_rotations([A,B,C,D], Xss).
Xss = [[B,C,D,A],
         [C,D,A,B],
           [D,A,B,C]].           % succeeds deterministically
```

Comment: Thanks this is exactly what I was looking for! One more question though, how could I alter it such that the original list isn't in the final list? (like [A,B,C,D] isn't included).

Answer (score 1):

A solution to your problem could be:

```
rotatelist([H|T], R) :- append(T, [H], R).

rotate(L,LO,LL):-
    rotatelist(L,L1),
    \+member(L1,LO),!,
    append([L1],LO,L2),
    rotate(L1,L2,LL).
rotate(_,L,L).

?- rotate([1,2,3,4],[],L).
L = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [4, 1, 2, 3], [3, 4, 1, 2], [2, 3, 4, 1]]
```

Simply rotates the list and checks if this list has already been inserted in the output list. If not the recursion continues, otherwise it returns the list in `L`. I've inserted the cut `!` just to have only the list with all the possible rotations. If you want generate also the other lists just remove it...

If instead you want a solution with the prototype you provide, it could be:

```
rotatelist([H|T], R) :- append(T, [H], R).

all_shifts(_,[],I,I).
all_shifts(L,Result,Len,I):-
    I < Len,
    rotatelist(L,LO),
    I1 is I+1,
    all_shifts(LO,R1,Len,I1),
    append([LO],R1,Result).

?- length([1,2,3,4],L), all_shifts([1,2,3,4],R,L,1).
L = 4,
R = [[2, 3, 4, 1], [3, 4, 1, 2], [4, 1, 2, 3]]
```

The idea is basically the same as before... Note that this second solution is not tail recursive.

Comment: No need for `append/3`: `append([LO],R1,Result)` can be simply rewritten as `Result = [LO| R1]`.